# Como passar informação da segunda ViewController para a primeira ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

Estou com problemas para passar uma informação da segunda tela de um `NavigationViewController` para a primeira tela da `NavigationViewController`.
Em alguns sites gringos eu achei ensinando a fazer por Protocolo, mas não está funcionando. 
Há um modo mais fácil e pratico de fazer?

Obs: A primeira tela é uma `ViewController` normal e a segunda é uma `TableViewController` que deve enviar as informações da célula selecionada para a primeira tela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direção que você deve tomar é justamente esta que você encontrou, através de protocolo. É bem simples e isso é independente se é `TableViewController` ou não.

Vamos supor que você tenha a `PrimeiraViewController` e `SegundaViewController`. Nesta segunda, no seu arquivo de cabeçalho **.h**, criamos o protocolo (antes da declaração *@interface*):

```
@protocol SegundaViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)foo:(id)bar;
@end
```

E nesse mesmo arquivo, a propriedade:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<SegundaViewDelegate> segundaViewDelegate;
```

No arquivo de implementação **.m**, seja onde for que você irá passar esse valor, você chama esse método:

```
[self.segundaViewDelegate foo:[NSDate date]]
```

Aqui eu passei um `NSDate` só de exemplo, naturalmente, mas você pode criar seu método como e onde você quiser, no seu caso será quando uma célula for pressionada.

Na `PrimeiraViewController`, adicionamos este delegate no **.h**:

```
@interface PrimeiraViewController : UIViewController <SegundaViewDelegate>
```

E quando a segunda tela é acionada, definimos este *delegate*:

```
SegundaViewController *viewController = [[SegundaViewController alloc] init];
[viewController setSegundaViewDelegate:self];
```

E implementamos o método que iremos receber as informações:

```
- (void)foo:(id)bar {
    NSLog("%@", bar);
}
```

Veja se consegue entender e implementar desta forma.

Comment: A alocação da 'SegundaViewController' devo fazer no prepareForSegue?

Comment: @DavidBatista Isso, já que você usa Storyboard, a alocação é na `prepareForSegue:` mesmo, só alterando para `SegundaViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController]`.

Comment: Acredito que este tenha sido meu erro quando testei na primeira vez. Mais tarde farei essa alteração e testar novamente.