# Como passar dados de uma ViewController para outra ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Pesquisando sobre isso encontrei algumas soluções, a primeira é passar pelo `prepareForSegue()`, a segunda é usar uma variável compartilhada (global), também cheguei a ver uma coisa sobre usar protocolo, mas não consegui usar.

Em alguns casos, em que um app que possui vários níveis ou usa uma biblioteca como *SWRevealViewController*(slide out menu), é difícil ficar passando dados e usar variáveis globais. Sempre fui recomendado a não usar em outras linguagens de programação.

Assim, segundo as melhores práticas, qual a forma de passar dados de uma *ViewController* para outra.

Comment: Editei de forma a torná-la mais fácil de ler e tentei que não seja considerada como "baseada em opiniões"[(veja porquê)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Não sei nada de *swift* mas se "protocolo" é o equivalente a "interfaces" em *Java* e se puder ser feita uma analogia com o Android, então usar "protocolo" poderá ser uma solução. Talvez esta [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10418/2541) possa ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há várias formas de passar informações entre os objetos e a maneira certa vai depender das características da aplicação.

Usando propriedades:
Normalmente usado quando a dado é passado uma única vez, tão logo o objeto é alocado. Creio que essa foi a forma que você fez. Define-se as propriedades do segundo controller e quando aloca-lo, modifica os valores dessas propriedades:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var data: String?
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    ...
    //Utilizando segues para transição
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
            destinationViewController.data = "foo"
        }
    }

    //Definindo as transições programaticamente
    @IBAction func openDetail(sender: UIView) {

        let destinationViewController = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
        destinationViewController.data = "foo"
        presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Protocolos: Outra forma bastante utilizada é através de protocolos, como sugeriu o @ramaral, veja a [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10418/como-passar-informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-segunda-viewcontroller-para-a-primeira-viewcontroller) que trata isso. Normalmente utilizamos protocolos quando os dados são passados de forma assíncrona. Ex: o segundo controller solicita dados ao primeiro sob demanda, a medida que o usuário faz scroll na tela. Sugiro estudar os padrões *delegate* e *datasource*, largamente usados no iOS.

Um outro padrão muito usado para comunicação é o *singleton*, mas ele não deve ser usado pra comunicação direta entre dois objetos. *Singletons* são melhor utilizados para manter o estado global da aplicação.